# NodeJS Writing JPG from Byte Array

Tags: php, node.js, actionscript-3, jpeg, fs

I have an AS3 application sending me a jpeg-encoded byte array from an http post. My node application is to take that, and save it on the local filesystem as a jpg.

the as3 jpeg-encoder is from [as3 core lib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

Code:

```
var results = new Object();
    results.success = false;
    results.message = debugWrite("Post Recieved \r\n");
    processPost(request, response, function() {

        results.message += debugWrite("path: " + FILEPATH + "\r\n");

        //save jpg
        var buffer = new Buffer(request.post, 'binary');
        fs.writeFile(FILEPATH, buffer, "binary", function(error){
            if(error != null){
                results.message +=debugWrite("Error: "+ error + "\r\n");
            }else{
                results.message += debugWrite("OK - Saved");
                results.success = true;
            }
        });

        response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        response.write(JSON.stringify(results));
        response.end();
    });
}

var processPost = function(request, response, callback) {
    var queryData = "";
    if(typeof callback !== 'function') return null;

    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        request.on('data', function(data) {
            queryData += data;
            if(queryData.length > 1e6) {
                debugWrite("Request To Large");
                queryData = "";
                response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}).end();
                request.connection.destroy();
            }
        });

        request.on('end', function() {
            request.post = queryData;
            callback();
        });

        } else {
            response.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end();
        }
}
```

Currently it is saving a file, however, the file isn't view-able.
Any tips are really appreciated.

php accomplished the task using "file_put_contents", but i needed to move the functionality to a node server.

Comment: `new Buffer(data, encoding)` is deprecate. Use `Buffer.from(data, encoding)` instead. Try add `console.log(request.post)`. If buffer data is ok then bites on start must be equals bites from any jpeg-file, e.g. `FF D8 FF E0 00 10 46 4A 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60` (it's permanent jpeg-file header).

Comment: @AikonMogwai fd fd fd fd 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 are the start bytes im getting. also, the tail bytes are incorrect. where else could recieving the bytes differ from the previous php script i was using?

Comment: Can you post image received by php as file? I found that header can be changed by some jpg version :(

Comment: Perhaps, headers've got a finite number. And `fd fd fd fd` is not one of them. I think problem in difference how Node and php store buffer (it have some variant, e.g. little-endian and big-endian)

Comment: @AikonMogwai i got a version working. Thanks so much for your help. after doing a few logs out, i logged the raw data, and found it was perfect even though the "queryData" was not. i rewrote the function to write on data instead of throwing them all together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data from the request on data event was perfect, so i used a writestream. Somehow, collecting all the data messed up the information.

Code:

```
//server handling route
if(QD === "/postImage"){
    processPost(request, response, filename);
}

var processPost = function(request, response, name) {
    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        //repsonse object
        var results = new Object();
        results.success = false;
        results.message = debugWrite("Post Recieved \r\n");
        results.message += debugWrite("HREF: " + name + "\r\n");

        //make write stream
        var ImageFile = fs.createWriteStream(PATH+'/public/assets/'+name);

        //on data
        request.on('data', function(data) {
            //write to file
            ImageFile.write(data);
        });

        //on end
        request.on('end', function() {
            //finish write
            ImageFile.end();
            response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.write(JSON.stringify(results));
            response.end();
        });

    } else {
        response.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        response.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding **encoding: 'binary'** to the request solved the problem with (fd fd fd fd....)

```
request.get({url: url_snapshot, encoding: 'binary'}
```